# making this sorting algorithm work to produce desired output, round robin

Tags: java, algorithm, round-robin

i have an arraylist named "processes" that holds objects (num, arrival, burst), which is also sorted by arrival time(first to last). I have to produce the desired output, i was able to figure out the algorithm for first come first served, but i am having a lot of trouble with the Round robin one. I also have a queue sorted by arrival time, if thats perhaps an easier alternative? any help would be appreciated, thanks!

> this is the input file i am reading, parsing it, creating the arraylist of objects from.

[image: input]

> this is the output. i used a selected and finished variables for fcfs, i supposed we have to use the same for this one

[image: output]

Comment: Can we see what you've tried already? What trouble did you have?

Answer (score 0):

For Round Robin you will need to cycle through the list of your processes. Consider this pseudocode:

```
  while queue.isNotEmpty:
    For each ProcessId in Processes:
       Find the oldest entry for that process in your FIFO
       Execute that entry
    Reset to beginning of list of ProcessIds
```

Then you will get a RoundRobin approach.